# Content search web part, query search, is it possible to perform this filter

Tags: publishing-page, query, content-search-web-part

I have one CSWP that displays article pages from a single site. The article pages have 2 different tags (a & b).

I would like the tags a to always be displayed, no matter how much time passes, while the tags b to be no longer displayed after 180 days from the article date.

Is it possible to match a condition for each tag?

I know I can create an extra field to make the article page 'sticky' while the other 'expires' but I wanted to know if there was a chance to accomplish this without the extra field.

Answer (score 0):

I you have the possibility i would recommend You to use a Content Search Web Part instead and edit its Query so that it displays Your articles based on ((Article = A) or (Article=B & DateCriteria)).

Comment: my mistake, i meant cswb, if i have a yes/no field, is it treated as Field=Yes?